# add class to element on hover in blazor

Tags: blazor

Note I can't just use CSS `:hover` because I'll also need to modify the class property on these elements based on `keydown` on a different element, and even if the mouse is still hovering it could loose the class until the `mousemove` happens again.

So having a list like this:

```
<ul>
<li> item1 </li>
...
</ul>
```

I need to add a class to `li` tag when only when `mousemove` triggers on it

is this possible with blazor ? or only with jsinterop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `@onmouseover` and `@onmouseout` events

```cs
<li class="@MyClass" @onmouseover="MouseOver" @onmouseout="MouseOut">

@code {
  string MyClass { get; set; }
  void MouseOver(MouseEventArgs e) { MyClass="over"; }
  void MouseOut(MouseEventArgs e) { MyClass=""; }
}
```

You can combine the `MyClass` property however you wish with the other events

Comment: will this work even if the `li` is inside a for loop ?

Comment: @buga no, not unless you have a list of strings (or a dictionary or something) as `MyClass` and specify which one it is that you want to change, but that was not mentioned in the question

Comment: ok, I guess if I do have a loop going js interop will make things easier, not sure how well it will perform to have a list full of @MyClass, and also I'll need a list full of @refs for each `li`

Comment: You'd be ok with having an array of strings or something and just use the index... but yes, if you just want to have access to the DOM element (not to the actual component in Blazor server), JSInterop would be the way to go. Make sure you add a `@key` in Blazor (which you should, for any "looped component") so that Blazor doesn't lose track of the element if you change the DOM around it from Javascript

Comment: For the loop problem if @Jcl 's  code was a serarate component and the component was inside the loop not just the `<li>` would work.

Comment: That's actually right, if you put all this inside a separate component, it'd work "as is", but since in the question you state there are other external things that modify the class, I didn't make such assumptions

Comment: I guess the myClass shoule be MyClass, correct?

Comment: @SharifYazdian that's right